# Which type to use for checkbox fields in hook_field_schema?

Tags: 7, entities, database

**Task:**

Create a custom field which contains a single checkbox by implementing [`hook_field_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) etc.

**Question:**

Which [data type](https://drupal.org/node/159605) is (or should) be used to define the corresponding database column to save checkbox values?

**Sample code:**

```
function field_test_field_schema ($field)
{
    $columns = array();
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'test':
            $columns = array(
                    'value' => array(
                            'type' => '???',
                            'not null' => TRUE
                    ),
            );
            break;
    }
    return array('columns'=> $columns);
}
```

**Update:**
[`node_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.install/function/node_schema/7) uses `int` for boolean columns. e.g. :

```
'status' => array(
  'description' => 'Boolean indicating whether the node is published (visible to non-administrators).',
  'type' => 'int',
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'default' => 1,
)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A tiny `int` would be most appropriate in my opinion:

```
$columns = array(
  'value' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'default' => 0,
  ),
);
```

A 'standard' `int` would be overkill for a field that will only ever hold a `0` or `1` value.

See the [Data types](https://drupal.org/node/159605) docs for an overview of the different types available to you.

Answer (score 7):

There is no boolean in the Drupal schema API so you just use a tiny int.  Below is an example of a checkbox for a member where checked is "blocked" and unchecked is "in good standing":

```
  'status' => array(
    'description' => '0 = in good standing; 1 = blocked',
    'type' => 'int',
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

pgsql worked sample:

```
'has_original' => array(
  'pgsql_type' => 'boolean',
  'type' => 'int',
  'size' => 'tiny',
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
```